# Each automorphism is of that form

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $c,b\in R$ with $c$ invertible.

The correspondence $x\rightarrow cx+b$ defines an unique automophism of $R[x]$ that is the identity in $R$.

If $D$ is an integral domain then I want to show that each automorphism of $D[x]$ that is trivial in $D$ is of the above form.

What exactly means "trivial in $D$" ? Is it maybe the identity in $D$ ?

Suppose that $\phi:D[x]\rightarrow D[x]$ is an automorphsism. So we suppose that it is a polynomial and then we have to show that this polynomial is of first degree?

How can we show then that the automorphism is trivial in $D$ ?

Comment: (1) Identity on $D$, yes. (2) Any ring endomorphism that is trivial on $D$ must be polynomial in this sense. (3) You are assuming that the automorphism is trivial on $D$.

Comment: Let $\phi : D[x]\rightarrow D[x]$ be an automorphism of $D[x]$ that is trivial on $D$. Do we consider the correspondence $x\rightarrow f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is a polynomial, so $\phi (p(x))=p(f(x))$ ? @Hoot

Answer (score 4):

"trivial in $D$" is bad use of the word. What you want to determine are the $D$-algebra automorphisms (i.e. ring automorphisms that are also $D$-linear). Such an automorphism is determined by the image of $X$. What you want to show first is that $\phi(X)$ is a linear polynomial. Consider degrees! $X$ must lie in the image!

Comment: So, is the automorphism the following? $$\phi : D[x]\rightarrow D[x] \\ \phi (p(x))=p(f(x))$$ where $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $D[x]$ ?